# What is the best low-rank approximation of a non-negative matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have a ***non-negative matrix $X$*** and I compute its Singular Value Decomposition:
$$X = U \Sigma V^T$$
then, I take the lower rank approximization:
$$X_k = U_k \Sigma_k V^T_k$$
where $k < rank(X)$, $U_k$ is made of the first $k$ columns of $U$, $\Sigma_k$ is the $k \times k$ diagonal matrix whose elements are the first $k$ singualar values of $X$ and $V_k$ is composed of the first $k$ columns of the $V$ matrix.

$$X = X_k + N_{svd}$$

My measure of "loss of information" is $||X-X_k||_F^2$.

My question is:

1. Can I minimize this loss any further?
2. What is the idea of ***non-negative matrix factorization under noisy separability***. and is it an answer to Q1?

Comment: 1. No, that's the best you can do with $\text{rank}X_k\le k$, but **do not expect your $X_k$ to be non-negative**.

Comment: You might find this method helpful.  http://sifter.org/~simon/journal/20061211.html

Comment: @ A.G....How can I prove that $X_k$ is not necessarily non-negative